# Cannot Update Software

Tags: update-manager

Using software updater returns an error - any help is greatly appreciated.
Here are the updateable packages

[image]

Here is the error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this using Synaptic Package Manager, searching for upgrades and manually upgrading all things mesa related.  After that software updater worked without error.

[image: Packages Upgraded Using Synaptic]